# ASP.Net MVC 3 Custom Membership provider backed by services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I need to create a login page with a password reset workflow that includes sending a link to the user's email to the page to set their new password. I was thinking of using a Custom membership provider however, our system uses a back-end identity management system that all creation, validation and updates go through. All the examples I see for creating custom membership providers use a direct db connection. This will not work for me. So, I was wondering if it is advised, or even possible, to create a membership provider that does through a services back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use services for your data access. You'll probably have to execute them synchronously, though.

Do you have the source and/or libraries for your identity management system? If so, you could access it directly in your provider, cutting out the service layer.

Comment: I have the source but it's all Node.js and mongodb. So, I will be going through the service layer. ;-) Can I just leave out the connection string in the web.config?

Comment: Answer is yes. Works perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Right, some of the configuration is specific to the provider implementation. So settings like connectionString would not apply.